# Loading an assembly throws exception 

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to load an assembly but getting exception that `File is already in use by another process` .

Actually I have a project opened in `Visual Studio` and other program is loading one dll created by `Visual Studio` following is the code for loading the assembly:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
```

Actually I want to load an assembly and read all types and properties of types and show them in my application.

I am able to get all types and properties and it works if `Visual Studio` is not opened but If I try to use any dll which is used by VS I get the same exception.

In some programs like `Reflector`, it's possible to load a `dll` while it is used in `VS`.
Maybe there is another way to do it.

Comment: It will be the debugger host process that is holding the lock on your assembly. The answer is simple - make sure that project is not loaded in VS when you try to load that assembly.

Comment: @slugster: Is there any way to do both at the same time I see other program like Reflector, there we can have it at the same time.

Comment: This is not normal.  Probably some add-in that you've got installed that does this.  Disable them one by one.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have dot peek installed on my machine and it works quite well, is there no way I can avoid this problem.